# How or when get invoice it's increment id

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice

I need to work with invoice, just after it's payed but already has increment_id.

Is there event after invoice save? Or which function generate increment_id, so i can create plugin on it.

Thanks.

---

*PS: I tried those to observe those two events, but none of them gave me invoice with increment_id.*

- *sales_order_invoice_register*
- *sales_order_invoice_pay*

Answer (score 0):

Following class is responsible for generating increment_id

**Magento/SalesSequence/Model/Sequence.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve next value
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNextValue()
{
    $this->connection->insert($this->meta->getSequenceTable(), []);
    $this->lastIncrementId = $this->connection->lastInsertId($this->meta->getSequenceTable());
    return $this->getCurrentValue();
}
```

So you can use plugin for any modification. Its global function for order, invoice, shipment, creditmemo.

You can pass registry param from

**\Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Manager**

As an example:

```
/**
 * Returns sequence for given entityType and store
 *
 * @param string $entityType
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Sequence\SequenceInterface
 */
public function aroundGetSequence(
    \Magento\SalesSequence\Model\Manager $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $entityType,
    $storeId
)
{
    // $entityType is 'order' or 'shipment' or 'invoice' or 'creditmemo'
    $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('sr_entityType', $entityType);
    return $proceed($entityType, $storeId);
}
```

Now you get this registry param from **getNextValue** and modify your own way.

Comment: I don't actually need to edit it. I just need to get it to external SW, but without breaking functionality of other modules, that modify increment_id. I'm not sure if this is exactly what i can use.  I will investigate this further, but anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement, I need to get invoice information after invoice save from admin.

I fulfil the requirement using the event observer. 
**app/code/Anshu/Customization/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_sales_order_invoice_save">
        <observer name="observer_admin_invoice_save" instance="Anshu\Customization\Observer\AnshuInvoiceSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Customization/Observer/AdminInvoiceSave.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Customization\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AnshuInvoiceSave implements ObserverInterface 
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
    */

   protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
        $invoice = $this->getInvoiceObject();
        // My Customization
    }

    private function getInvoiceObject()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_invoice');
    }

}
```

Check if it is helpful to you. 
Magento version was 2.2.1